# What is the proper aproach for agregational like queries?

Tags: xodus

looking into Java query approach or Kotlin based DNQ can't see how to make queries similar to 'group by' ... What is a proper approach for such queries? E.g. when I have invoices entities and I would like to group these by company name and sum of sales.

Comment: Please describe in more detail what is the company name -- just string property, or link to a dictionary value?

Comment: Just string property. I just went through txn.getAll(..) and grouped values using Java 8 streams. Took cca. 1.5s compared to 600ms in MongoDB (used aggregations) and 120ms in PosrgresSQL(used SQL groupy by clause) for the same data. Around 230K items in database.

Comment: It probably would be faster to go though `((PersistentStoreTransaction)txn).findWithPropSortedByValue(..)` instead of `txn.getAll(..)`. This method returns entities having specified property sorted by the property value, so groupping code may be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this can help you achieve an emulated "GROUP BY":

```
  entityStore.executeInTransaction(
      new StoreTransactionalExecutable() {
        @Override
        public void execute(@NotNull final StoreTransaction txn) {
          txn.getEntityTypes().forEach(type -> {
            EntityIterable result = txn.getAll(type);
            long count = result.count();
          });
        }
      });
```

Essentially what this does is it queries all entity types and then do a count, similar to what GROUP BY does. From here you can just create a Map or something to put both the entity type and count in the map.